# redirect after login using $location.path(lastPath); will not re-run controller constructor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have written a redirect service interceptor in anagular:

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
.factory('loginRedirectInterceptor', _loginRedirectInterceptor);

function _loginRedirectInterceptor($q, $location) {

    var lastPath = "/";

    var loginRedirector = {
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 401) {
                lastPath = $location.path() == "/login" ? "/" : $location.path();
                $location.path("/login");
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        },
        redirectPostLogin: function () {
            $location.path(lastPath);
            lastPath = "/";
        },

    };

    return loginRedirector;
}
```

so when there is a API call from a give controller that returns a 401 i redirect to login while saving the requested path and then exposing a function `redirectPostLogin` that is called by `LoginController` after a successfull login.

all works fine and redirects as expected but the call that is made in the controller constructor never gets called again ...
is there another way to achive what i need or can i somehow force the  `$location.path(lastPath);` to reload the controller in the relevant path ?

Answer (score 0):

So you are using routing in you app right, for this you can utilize route changing state which will hold information of the executing current state controller or path , the previous one and next one.

**Like the ngRoute service, the angular-route service fires events at different times during the state lifecycle.**

We can attach functions to these events inside of our application by listening on the $scope. All of the following events are fired on the $rootScope, so we can listen to these events on any of our $scope objects.

### State Change Events

We can listen to the events as follows:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams), {
// We can prevent this state from completing
evt.preventDefault();
});
```

The events that may be fired are as follows:

**$stateChangeStart** This event is fired when the transition from one state to another begins.

**$stateChangeSuccess** This event is fired when the transition from one state to the next is completed.

**$stateChangeError** This event is fired when an error occurs during the transition. It is usually caused by either a template that cannot be resolved or a resolve promise failing to resolve.

**This is not exact solution or answer as you want, but you will need to go through it and test this all by debugging for better knowledge.**

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to Angular2.0.

then use like:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/">Dashboard</a>
```